# How to edit Parse.com users with Javascript

Tags: parse-platform, permissions, clp

All I want to do is set a boolean that all the users have to false using a Javascript tool. I'm getting "Error 206: ParseUserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError" when I try to do so. The user I log in as for the tool has an "Administrator" role that has read/write CLP for the User table.

In this blog (http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-iii-are-you-on-the-list/) they briefly mention the Master Key, but never explain how to use it. This: https://www.parse.com/questions/masterkey-in-nodejs didn't work either, the script wouldn't even run.

Can someone please tell me how to use the master key in JS like Parse probably should somewhere in their documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the master key while initializing the Parse. You can do this,

```
Parse.initialize( applicationId, javaScriptKey, masterKey)
```

more information can be found [here](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.html).

Hope this helps.